# spacy multi label classification help

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, multiclass-classification, spacy

I would like to create a multilabel text classification algorithm using SpaCy text multi label.  I am unable to understand the following questions:

1. How to convert the training data to SpaCy format i.e I have 8 categories
2. After converting, how do we use that to train custom categories and apply different models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro. It's waste to do classification using spaCy, you can refer Deep learning techniques. But your question is different, spaCy needs dictionary format with labels Positive and negative, Here I will give sample snippet, like this frame your input data

```
# change input data to spaCy readable format
```

train_examples = []  # it needs dict inside tuples insides dictionary (you will understand down)

for index, row in reviews_df.iterrows():
text = row['Text']
rating = row['Score']

```
label = {"POS": True, "NEG": False} if rating == 1 else {'NEG':True, 'POS': False}

train_examples.append( Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), {'cats': label}) )
```

You can refer this https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/custom-text-classification-spacy/ Clearly explained, Use Bert dude, BERT is SOTA model, that gives more accurate results, See here [https://analyticsindiamag.com/a-beginners-guide-to-text-classification-using-bert-features/#:~:text=what%20BERT%20is.-,What%20is%20BERT%3F,both%20left%20and%20right%20context](https://analyticsindiamag.com/a-beginners-guide-to-text-classification-using-bert-features/#:%7E:text=what%20BERT%20is.-,What%20is%20BERT%3F,both%20left%20and%20right%20context).